# How to display an acknowledgement prompt showing what has been entered when user inputs info into text fields and clicks submit in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Was wondering how to display an acknowledgement prompt using javascript when user inputs info into textfields on a form that shows what they have entered e.g. "Hello 'user' you have entered this comment: 'comment'"

Ive been trying using variables and an alert box but haven't been able to get it to work:

```
    function updateTxt() {
        var content1 = document.getElementById('name').innerText;
        var content2 = document.getElementById('email').innerText;
        var content3 = document.getElementById('comments').innerText;
        var content4 = document.getElementById('rating').value;
           alert("Dear: " + frm.content1.value,"thank you for your  feedback, you rated us "frm.content4.value" and this is your comment: " frm.content3.value) 
  }
```

(content4 is from a radio button)

This is the form code with a validation function and the submit button code:

```
     <form name="Feedback" action="#"onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

     <input type="submit" onclick="updateTxt()" value="Submit">
```

Just looking for pointers to see if I've missed anything, thanks in advance

Comment: I have the functions in seperate script tags does this affect it in any way?

Comment: No, as long as they are loaded in the same order they are called

Comment: Would it have to do with the way im calling the function? Does it matter that I haven't included the function within onsubmit?

Comment: Check the jsFiddle in my answer

Comment: Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing some `+`'s in your alert. Also I'm not sure what `frm` is, but you shouldn't need to reference it based on the example.

```
function updateTxt() {
  var content1 = document.getElementById('name').innerText;
  var content2 = document.getElementById('email').innerText;
  var content3 = document.getElementById('comments').innerText;
  var content4 = document.getElementById('rating').value;
  alert("Dear: " + content1 + ", thank you for your feedback, you rated us " + content4 + " and this is your comment: " + content3) 
}
```

[Working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3j3odq2x/1/)

Comment: I've added the +'s to the alert and it still isn't working

Comment: @Harv - you need to be more specific than "still isn't working".  Are you getting errors? Are you looking in your browser developer console? What happens / doesn't happen?

Comment: There were no errors it just simply didn't display a dialog box prompt from my aforementioned code, everything else was working. I can see now I needed to add if conditionals